# access the last three Characters of the value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value "319CDXB"  everytime i have to access last three characters of the Strring how can i do this . Usually the Length varies all the time .Everytime I need the last characters of the String using Jquery

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [String `.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) lets you use a negative index:

```
var str = "319CDXB".slice( -3 ); // DXB
```

---

**EDIT:** To expound a bit, the `.slice()` method for String is a method that behaves very much like its [Array counterpart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

The first parameter represents the starting index, while the second is the index representing the stopping point.

Either parameter allows a negative index to be employed, as long as the range makes sense. Omitting the second parameter implies the end of the String.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/N4Z93/

```
var str = "abcdefg";

str.slice(0);        // "abcdefg"
str.slice(2);        // "cdefg"
str.slice(2,-2);     // "cde"
str.slice(-2);       // "fg"
str.slice(-5,-2);    // "cde"
```

The other nice thing about `.slice()` is that it is widely supported in all major browsers. These two reasons make it (in my opinion) the most appealing option for obtaining a section of a String.

Comment: Negative indexes are not supported in IE

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Yes they are. I'm using `.slice()` not `.substr()`. And by the way, *Grrrr...* for making me fire up IE in VMWare to double check. ;o)

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I subconsciously concluded that IE doesn't like negative indexes at all.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - That's alright. It's usually a safer bet that something *doesn't* work in IE. :o)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with regular JavaScript:

```
var str = "319CDXB";
var lastThree = str.substr(str.length - 3);
```

If you're getting it from jQuery via .val(), just use that as your str in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
str = "319CDXB"
last_three = str.substr(-3)
```

Comment: This is not supported in IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0esxc5wy.aspx

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp it is, but I'm on a mac, so I can't test it.

Comment: According to that page, it isn't. It says it right there (under Tips and notes)

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "319CDXB";
str.substr(str.length - 3); // "DXB"
```